# Modifying a particular observable attribute on n items in an observableArray?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm doing an interface in which one object in an observableArray can be `selected` when you click on it. Any currently `selected` objects (of which there should be only one) in the array should have their (its) `selected` observable changed.

Do I need to iterate over the entire array on click, setting all `selected`s to false before setting the clicked element's `selected` to true, like so?

```
self.selectAnnotation = function() {
  var array = //annotations array from AnnotationsViewModel
  // (actually, I'm not so sure of the syntax of this either)

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    var item = array[i];
    item.selected(0);
  }
  self.selected(1);
}
```

With a binding that looks like this:

```
<div id="clickArea" data-bind="foreach: annotations">   
    <span data-bind="click: selectAnnotation, css: selected: selected" class="annotation"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the selected item in the parent context, so not in each item.

```
var ViemModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.annotations= [...];
    self.selected = ko.observable();
    self.selectAnnotation = function(annotation) {
        self.selected(annotation);
    };
};

<div id="clickArea" data-bind="foreach: annotations">   
    <span data-bind="click: $parent.selectAnnotation, css: { 'selected': $parent.selected() == $data}" class="annotation"></span>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much! :)

Am I correct to assume that `$data` represents the current ko object in the foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, $data is always the current bound object, but only in a loop, everywhere.
So when you write : foreach: annotations it means foreach: $data.annotations.
Consider the $data as the this keyword.